# Finding the Cramer-Rao Lower Bound

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference

> Given the probability density function $$f(x; \theta) = \frac{ \left(\ln(\theta)\right)^{x}}{\theta x!}, \quad x = 0,1,\ldots ; \theta > 1$$ and $0$ otherwise, find the Cramer-Rao Lower Bound for $\theta$.

I found a complete sufficient statistic for $\theta$ to be $S = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$ and the Max-Likelihood Estimator of $\theta$ to be $ \hat{\theta} = e^{\bar{X}}$ where $ \bar{X} = { \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_{i}}{n}}$. Also $$\frac{d}{d\theta} \ln \left(L(\theta)\right)= \frac{-n}{\theta} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}}{ \theta \ln(\theta)}$$

How do I find the CRLB for $\theta$ from here?

Comment: What happened when you tried to apply the general procedure?

Comment: I have used the form $\frac{1}{ E( \frac{d}{d\theta} ln(L(\theta))^{2})}$ to find the CRLB, but I get a nasty expression and I am wondering if there is an easier way to find it or a theorem that allows me to apply my complete sufficient statistic or my Max-Likelihood Estimator.

Comment: Using the alternative expression $I(\theta)=-E\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\ln L(x,\theta)\right)$ yields readily the result.

Comment: Ok, so I get $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\ln L(x,\theta) = \frac{n}{\theta^{2}} - \frac{\sum x_{i}}{ \theta^{2} (ln(\theta))^2} + \frac{\sum x_{i}}{ \theta^{2} ln(\theta) } $ Then, how would I take the Expectation ?

Comment: I am not sure what the Expectation of the probability density function is.

Comment: Well, $E(x_i)=\log\theta$ for every $i$, no? (But you should check the signs in your comment.)

Comment: Why is the $E(x_{i}) = log(\theta)$ for every $i$? You are right, there should be a negative in front of the second sum.

Comment: Sorry, I see why now, because this pdf has the form of a Poisson where $\mu = \log \theta$